# How to set Proxy setting for Chrome in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to set proxy settings for Firefox as below.

```
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL); 

proxy.setHttpProxy(CONFIG.getProperty("hostname"));
proxy.setSslProxy(CONFIG.getProperty("hostname"));
proxy.setFtpProxy(CONFIG.getProperty("hostname"));
proxy.setSocksUsername(CONFIG.getProperty("username"));
proxy.setSocksPassword(CONFIG.getProperty("password"));
FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
fp.setProxyPreferences(proxy);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(fp);
builder = new Actions(driver); 
bckdbrowser = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, ConfigReader.ENVIRONMENT_URL);
```

But I need to setup for Chrome as well.. Can any one assist me how to do ?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try using the `DesiredCapabilities` class, like this:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=http://user:password@proxy.com:8080"));
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: You mean should I give --proxy-server as it is ?

Comment: just use your own settings: `capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--proxy-server=http://" + CONFIG.getProperty("username") + ":" + CONFIG.getProperty("password") + "@" + CONFIG.getProperty("hostname")));`

Comment: it doesn't work for me. Which version of selenium and chrome was used?

Answer (score -6):

Try this code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 

profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal()); 

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

here we have one more solution....it's worked for me

Comment: He`s asked about Chrome driver only.