# Java Selenium: Using proxy with authentication

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pass Selenium Chrome driver through a proxy server.
The server uses username & password authentication.

When I try:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy("12.345.678.9");

capabilities.setCapability("java.net.socks.username", "my.email@website.com");
capabilities.setCapability("java.net.socks.password", "my_password");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

webDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Then I try to get a website with .get() method but I get an alert requiring the proxies username and password.

I tried to use in the get(): `http://my.username@website.com:password@someWebsite.com`
But it did not work as well.

Also tried:

```
String stringUrl = "http://www.someUrl.com";
URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

uc.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");

String userpass = "my.email@website.com" + ":" + "my_password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);   

InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
```

Any suggestions here?

Thanks guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set Proxy setting for Chrome in Selenium Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225507/how-to-set-proxy-setting-for-chrome-in-selenium-java)

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/New User");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

For this, solution http://my.username@website.com:password@someWebsite.com will work, OR you can use `AutoIT`

Comment: When it was a long long time ago but AutoIT was the only option that actually worked.

Comment: Are you sure that proxy is using in that case?