# How to fill out login and password in an alert for authentication?

Tags: python, selenium

A proxy server requires login and password by showing a pop for login and password.

I'm using firefox.

This doesn't work:

```
"https://login123:pass123@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx"
```

or

```
"login123:pass123@xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx"
```

So how do I fill out the inputs for login and password?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the proxy manually, typing and letting the browser save the password and then using this existing profile with python-selenium?

Comment: @alecxe, no, because I have a lot of proxies.

Comment: I'm willing to switch to Chrome driver if it can handle authentification.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225507/how-to-set-proxy-setting-for-chrome-in-selenium-java)?